# do a soql or report on workflow actions and rules?

Tags: force.com, workflow

I want to do a report on workflows and thier actions in my org. Can I do a soql or sosl for this type of info? What I want is something like

Workflow, Action,   Description,    Criteria,   Action Type,    Action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, SOQL and SOSL only search the data in your org. You are wanting to search the system's Metadata, which describes the schema. You would need to export the Metadata and parse the resulting XML.

To export the data you could:

1. Create a new project in the Force.com IDE and then add the components. The IDE will generate the XML for you.
2. Use the Ant Migration Tool, but you'd have to hand-code a package.xml to request the desired components. The IDE is easier.
3. If neither of the above is appealing, you could create a Change Set and then send it to a different org. Go to the destination org and open the Change Set. Each element will have a View Source link that contains its XML.

**Edit**

Useful links for the Migration Tool:

- http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Migration_Tool_Guide
- http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_deploying_ant.htm

Comment: Okay. I've never really used the MetaDat API... can you direct me to a gentle intro for a video as opposed to  the 300 page PDF SF puts out

Comment: I've added some intro links for you.